# How to return one result per found value with Mongo DB and regular expressions?

Tags: php, json, mongodb

Say I've got a cars collection. I would like to be able to search and find the different makes which the cars in my collection posses using regular expressions.

I know that

```
db.collection.find( { make: { $regex: 'chev', $options: 'i' } } );
```

Will return all the documents with the closest (same) matching make, followed by the second closest (same) matching make, followed by the 3rd etc.

How can I build a query so that once a regex query matches a make, it does not return any more documents with the same make?

For example, I have the following documents:

```
{_id:1,make:"chevrolet"}
{_id:2,make:"chevrolet"} 
{_id:3,make:"Chevrolet"} 
{_id:4,make:"chevy"}
{_id:5,make:"chevy"}
```

How would I query the collection so that it returns (capitalization not important):

```
{_id:1,make:"chevrolet"}
{_id:4,make:"chevy"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the aggregation framework in 2.2 you can do a group:

```
$db->col->aggregate(array(
    array('$match' => array('make' => new MongoRegex('/chev/i'))),
    array('$group' => array('_id' => '$make'))
));
```

Since it doesn't make much sense to bring back the `_id` from the collection upon grouping this will actually return:

```
{_id: 'chevy'},
{_id: 'chevrolet'}
```

Comment: This looks good, I'll find out more about aggregation and get back to you. Thanks :)